# How to create JSONB GIN index on complex json struction

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

```
{
    "elements": {
        "array": [
            {
                "childElements": {
                    "array": [
                        {
                            "nameStId": "8818"
                        }
                      ]
                  }
            }
        ]
}
```

I want PostgresSQL GIN index on nameStId value
Need suggestion how to achieve this

Then i want to query too.

Comment: You'll have to be a little bit more detailed than that. What exactly do you want to speed up?

Comment: I have query in where clause to find the element nameStId = 8818

Comment: Your example JSON is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

For indexing JSONB data, you must use the jsonb_path_ops operator class. The GIN index can be created as shown below:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_nameStId ON your_table_name USING GIN (your_jsonb_column -> 'elements' -> 'array' -> 0 -> 'childElements' -> 'array' -> 0 -> 'nameStId' jsonb_path_ops);
```

Use the GIN index in your WHERE clause as follows to search for elements where nameStId equals 8818:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name
WHERE your_jsonb_column @> '{"elements": {"array": [{"childElements": {"array": [{"nameStId": "8818"}]}}]}}';
```

This query does a JSONB containment query using the @> operator, and the performance of the query should be enhanced by the GIN index you established.

Hope it works :)

Comment: But you are using fix position in array